# How to rotate the object about an angle using qml qt3d (qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt3d

I want to rotate the object in the window screen. I am using Qt/QML/Qt3D.

I write some code [here](https://bitbucket.org/amahta/3d_viewer/src/master/) to add a button in the object window display screen. With the help of this button I could rotate the object in the display screen about (90 and 180) degrees.

QML source code:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0

import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("3D Viewer")

    header: ToolBar
    {
        ToolButton
        {
            text: "Open 3D Model"
            onPressed:
            {
                fileDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }

    FileDialog
    {
        id: fileDialog
        onAccepted:
        {
            sceneLoader.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
    }

    Scene3D
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        aspects: ["input", "logic"]
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

        Entity
        {
            id: sceneRoot

            Camera
            {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 30
                aspectRatio: 16/9
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 1000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d( 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
            }

            OrbitCameraController
            {
                camera: camera
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings
                {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer
                    {
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)
                        camera: camera
                    }
                },
                InputSettings
                {
                }
            ]

            Entity
            {
                id: monkeyEntity
                components: [
                    SceneLoader
                    {
                        id: sceneLoader
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the main question is: what (assume `Transform` component?) and where should be added code to this source file to change angle of loaded model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example of how to do this in Qt (not Qt3D):
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#rotation-prop

```
Rectangle {
   color: "red"
   x: 25; y: 25; width: 50; height: 50
   rotation: 30  // !
}
```

Also you can rotate around other axis, here is information about it:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rotation.html

Example:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "blue"
    transform: Rotation {
        origin.x: 25;
        origin.y: 25;
        axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 };
        angle: 45
    }
}
```

---

**Update. For Qt3D** use at least version 2.15 for `Qt3D.Core` and use `Transform`. Here is edited your code:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.15

import Qt3D.Core 2.15
import Qt3D.Render 2.15
import Qt3D.Input 2.15
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("3D Viewer")

    header: ToolBar
    {
        RowLayout {

            ToolButton
            {
                text: "Open 3D Model"
                onPressed:
                {
                    fileDialog.open()
                }
            }

            ToolButton
            {
                text: "Rotate"
                onPressed:
                {
                    transform.rotation = Qt.quaternion(1, 0.1, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FileDialog
    {
        id: fileDialog
        onAccepted:
        {
            sceneLoader.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
    }

    Scene3D
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        aspects: ["input", "logic"]
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

        Entity
        {
            id: sceneRoot

            Camera
            {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 30
                aspectRatio: 16/9
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 1000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d( 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
            }

            OrbitCameraController
            {
                camera: camera
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings
                {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer
                    {
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)
                        camera: camera
                    }
                },
                InputSettings
                {
                }
            ]

            Entity
            {
                id: monkeyEntity
                components: [
                    SceneLoader
                    {
                        id: sceneLoader
                    },
                    Transform {
                        id: transform
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.Sir if I want to add a new button in the window screen .for this I added some code in this main.qml(https://bitbucket.org/amahta/3d_viewer/src/master/main.qml).    so that when I click the button then object rotate about 90 and 180 degree.So please help me to write some code for button

Comment: Can you share with me 3D model that your app could load? It will help me to investigate your problem. Also, probably you can try to use `Transform` from `Qt 3D` module: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-transform.html

Comment: sir ,can you tell me that at where I add your code in my code so that my object interact with this rotate angle. and it successful run .

Comment: Sorry, this code is for standard controls. For Qt3D you should use another. But I can't test your code without your 3D models, so can't provide well-tested answer for *exactly* Qt3D. If you share 3D model - it'll try to edit answer for Qt3D specific.

Comment: for 3D model I have the .ply file .In my task when I select the .ply(3d model)  file qt screen display the 3D model .but model are not rotating only scaling .So please tell me how to rotate it using mouse  and without mouse I want to add the button so that when I click the button model rotate any angle which are given.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Comment: sir, can I specified the angle for rotation i.e Transform { id:transform angle:90 }

Comment: Yes, you can. Angle is specified as `quaternion` or `rotationX`, ..Y, ..Z as Euler angle

Comment: Sir,If I rotate the object on the same axis ,what will do it ? because I want to view the anterior posterior of the object.

Comment: hi sir , I have used  elevation and azimuth value to rotate the object on the same axis .so please tell me at where add  these two value(elevation and azimuth)?